# Zenity select disk/volume

Tags: shell-script, terminal, zenity

is it possible to select a disk/volume with zenity instead of a single file?
I know there is the `zenity --file-selection` command, but can you also select for example `/dev/sda1` ?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can change directory to `/dev` and tell the file-selector to focus on `sd*` and/or `mmcblk*` and/or `nvme*`.

The following picture shows how mkusb-dus can use the file-selector to select a drive. Here only sda, sdb etc are selected by the filter, but with `*` instead of `?` you would see also partitions.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem to work the way I need/want it. What I am trying to do is display a zenity box, where the user can select 1) a single file 2) a disk/volume. I the case 2) zenity should either display a list from where the user can choose the volume or opens a window like --file-selection window, but with mounted disks. I hope you understand what I mean. Thank you.

Comment: Then you should use `lsblk` with some suitable options, for example `lsblk -lo name,mountpoint` or `df` and 'filter' the output to get what you want and feed that to a zenity list.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. Do you know how I can modify `lsblk` command in such a way that the output contains logical name, size and device name? For example:                    /dev/sda1   16GB   SanDisk Ultra

Comment: `lsblk` prints the device name is only for the main device (not for partitions, you must store it (in a variable). `lsblk -o name,size,model` will print what you specified, but I think you want details about mountpoint too, otherwise partitions that are not mounted will be listed too. Please spend some time with `lsblk -h` and `man lsblk` and make a shellscript, that collects the data you want, and then feeds it to zenity.

Answer (score 0):

the way he is saying it is that you need to type

```
zenity --file-selection        --title "select disk"        --filename "/dev/sd*
```

for it to work.replace `sd*` with whatever type of disk you are using.